# Use SimpleMembershipProvider in wcf

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

I am trying to use entityframework in WCF application.
For the moment i managed to get this far :

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("ILottoEntities", "Users", "Id", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
SimpleMembershipProvider provider = (SimpleMembershipProvider)System.Web.Security.Membership.Provider;
string userName = "gmail@gmail.com";
string password = "gmail@gmail.com";
```

This code is working fine with no errors
But when i am trying to use :

```
bool result = WebSecurity.Login(userName, password, persistCookie: true);
```

I am getting :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have no idea what is `null`.

Comment: [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: When i encapsulate the login in try catch all i am getting is the ex that i copied.